# Grab tag styling with php domxpath

Tags: php, dom, domxpath

i have following html

```
<ul class="L1_1">
<li><div style="font-size:10pt;font-family:'Arial';">A, B, C</div></li></ul>
```

I am trying to grab the `<li>` with all the styling and tag.
Here what i have so far with domxpath

$garb1 = $xpath->query('//ul/li');

About code will grab and display "A, B, C",
I wanted to grab entire `<li>'s` style like this

```
<li><div style="font-size:10pt;font-family:'Arial';">A, B, C</div></li>
```

Is that possbile?

Thanks

Comment: Use `echo $dom->saveHTML( $garb1->item(0) );` (Replace `$dom` with your DOM object name)

Comment: `$objectname = new DOMDocument()` => `$objectname` is your object name.

Comment: This is what i have.  function returnXPathObject($item) {
 $xmlPageDom = new DomDocument();
 @$xmlPageDom->loadHTML($item);  
 $xmlPageXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlPageDom);
 return $xmlPageXPath; 
}$clget = curlGet('http://localhost/webscrap/test.html');
$xpath = returnXPathObject($clget)

$clget = curlGet('http://localhost/webscrap/test.html');
$xpath = returnXPathObject($clget)

$garb1 = $xpath->query('//ul/li');

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, you have to use this syntax for displaying HTML node:

```
echo $domobject->saveHTML( $node );
```

You use this function:

```
function returnXPathObject( $item ) 
{
    $xmlPageDom = new DomDocument(); 
    @$xmlPageDom->loadHTML( $item );    
    $xmlPageXPath = new DOMXPath( $xmlPageDom ); 
    return $xmlPageXPath;
}

$clget = curlGet( 'localhost/webscrape/master-tung-doc-test.html' ); 
$xpath = returnXPathObject( $clget );
```

The `DOMDocument` object name is `$xmlPageDom`, but the problem is that you can not access it, because it is inside a function.

To access it you can modify your function in this way:

```
function returnDomObject( $html ) 
{
    $dom = new DomDocument(); 
    @$dom->loadHTML( $html );   
    $xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom ); 
    return (object) array( 'dom' => $dom, 'xpath' => $xpath );
}

$clget = curlGet( 'localhost/webscrape/master-tung-doc-test.html' ); 
$dom = returnDomObject( $clget );

$garb1 = $dom->xpath->query( '//ul/li' );

echo $garb1->dom->saveHTML( $garb1->item(0) );
```

By this way, your function return an object with both DOM object and XPath object: you have only to modify the syntax to call it, using `$dom->xpath->` instead of `$xpath->` and `$dom->dom->` to access to DOM object.

Actually, IMHO, the best way might be to construct an extended DOMDocument class. If you are interested, I can show you an example.

Comment: Thanks fusion3k, let me give this a try.